# Should I really redirect http to https for all requests?

Tags: nginx, firefox

I found an issue where if I load a script module using protocol agnostic urls it won't load.

`<script type="module" src="//briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js"></script>`

If I server the html file from `http://localhost:8080` it won't load. I get a cors error. (cors headers are on the server so it should work)...however either the browsers don't like 301 redirects for protocol agnostic urls or I've overlooked something.

If I use https: it works fine: (even from http)

`<script type="module" src="https://briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js"></script>`

I'm using nginx...and I'm just curious what the proper way to handle this is

Comment: i removed the tag

Answer (score -1):

If you're using proxy for nginx then mentioning just `components/feed-list.js` without //briskreader.com should help. Check once

Comment: its going to be loaded from another domain.